# Refreshing Pivot Table clears Values and Column Labels fields

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

When I attempt to refresh an Excel Pivot table (by right click .. Refresh), all of the Column Labels & Values fields disappear, leaving only Row Label fields and an empty Pivot Table. How can I keep Columns Labels and Values fields the same, avoiding the behaviour described above, and refresh only the data.

I've noted that this only seems to occur when I open a spreadsheet sent from another person, or if somebody opens up a spreadsheet I created with Pivot Table in it.

I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: What is your *question*?  You want to know how to stop this behavior?  It's best to be explicit, thanks.

Comment: Yes, explicitly: how do i stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself after much trial/error-

The source table had Column Labels formatted as Dates for columns. (11/1/12 to represent Nov/12, 12/1/12 to represent Dec/12, etc.). However the Pivot Table Values/Column Labels were 'Nov/12', 'Dec/12', etc.

Changing the column names in the Source Data to match those in the Pivot Table ('Nov/12) fixed this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happening over and over again, but finally realized the titles of the cells weren't really disappearing. The color shading of the cells was changing to white and matching the text. I just wound up manually adjusting the cell colors after the refresh was complete.